# Web API Multiple authorization servers for single resource

Tags: asp.net, authorization, asp.net-web-api2

Hi I'm new to Web API and thus also securing them an I need help with the following situation, any help would be greatly appreciated.

I have a Web API that will have users that will sign in using 2 diffent authentication methods.

The first will be for employees of the company and they use Active Directory, ADFS has been setup.
The second will be for clients of the company and their accounts are managed by ASP.NET Identity, I'm using http://bitoftech.net/2014/06/01/token-based-authentication-asp-net-web-api-2-owin-asp-net-identity/ as a guide

What would be the best way to achieve this?

Comment: An application can be configured either for organizational accounts(SSO) or individual accounts. I guess you have to make 2 different applications for sign in and later redirect them to the desired api.

Comment: @Rachit, thank you I assume you would be able to do something like this then [Link](http://bitoftech.net/2014/09/24/decouple-owin-authorization-server-resource-server-oauth-2-0-web-api/)